# c# Read .csv from stream in Handler class

Tags: c#, handler, streamreader, valums-file-uploader

I am using Valum's AJAX File Uploader to upload the csv file. The code to initialize it is :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {          
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
            // path to server-side upload script
            action: 'handlers/PhoneNumberListHandler.ashx',
            buttonTitle: 'Upload Document',
            buttonText: ' Upload',
            allowedExtensions: ['csv'],
            sizeLimit: 1024000, // max size 
        });
    });


<div id="file-uploader"></div>
```

In c# handler class I have written the following code so far:

```
    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[request.ContentLength];
    Stream inputStream;
    string fileName;

    inputStream = request.InputStream;
    fileName = request["qqfile"];

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';'); // gives some abstract characters
        }
    }
```

My csv file have three columns Phone, Firstname, Lastname where first column is compulsory and rest are optional.

I am now stuck as I am not able to read the .csv file. Can someone please help me and suggest how can I read a csv file content from the stream or is there any other way to do it? I want to extract the csv content and save each line separately in database table.

**Update:** 
I made changes in saving the csv file and now the content look like this:

PhoneNumber,FirstName,LastName

11111,Taj,Mahal

22222,Oberai,

33333,,Lake Palace

44444,,

Modified the above code:

```
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();            
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');

            listA.Add(values[0]);               
        }
    }
```

I want to get the individual value of the columns and here I am getting a full line in one string. To get individual value I have to further split it with "," and get the values. I want to know is there a better way to do this?

Comment: First of all, if you can, use some csv library to read csv. There are many things to consider. However, if you only want to read csv that you created yourself ("you" = your software), then you may not need the overhead of a 3rd party dependency. Please add an example of a typical csv to your question.

Comment: Is the file load/reading working correctly? Note that a CSV file usually has a comma (,) separator, not a semi-colon (;). However, your question is too broad. You can initially add each line to a `List<string><string>` or similar but what database technology are you using?

Comment: doesnt csvhelper help? you mention abstract characters, what sort?

Comment: Did you also change the separator in your code (line.Split(';'))? Your content specifies a comma

Comment: I don't see a separater. I open the file in edit mode in notepad and see the above lines

Answer (score 1):

Converting CSV file to model  with reflection.
First of all  you could create model and set attributes with Name of CSV columns.
like this:

```
     public class UserInfo
    {
        [CSVColumn(ImportName = "FirstName"]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [CSVColumn(ImportName = "LastName"]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [CSVColumn(ImportName = "PhoneNumber"]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Other steps are reading first line for getting data about columns and based on property attributes of model set data from scv row to each model property:

```
     List<UserInfo> users = new List<UserInfo>();
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
            {
                //read first line with headers
                var metaDataLine = reader.ReadLine() ?? "";
                //get array with headers
                string[] csvMetada = metaDataLine.Split(',');  

                   while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    { 
                     // create model based on string data and columns metadata with columns                      
                     UserInfo newModel =   ConvertCSVToEntity(reader.ReadLine() ?? "", csvMetada);
                     users.add(newModel);
                    }
                }
```

converting method string csv row to model :

```
        public UserInfo convertCSVToEntity(string line, string[] csvMetada)
        {
            var values = line.Split(',');

            UserInfo newRecord = ConvertorHelper.ConvertCSVToEntity<UserInfo>(values, csvMetada);

            return newRecord;
        }


        public static T ConvertCSVToEntity<T>(string[] csvData, string[] csvMetada) where T : new()
        {
            T returnEntity = new T();
            var properties = returnEntity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var eachProperty in properties)
            {
                var csvAttribute = eachProperty.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CSVColumn)) as CSVColumn;
                if (csvAttribute != null)
                {
                    int csvIndex = Array.IndexOf(csvMetada, csvAttribute.ImportName);
                    if (csvIndex > -1)
                    {
                        var csvValue = csvData[csvIndex];

                        object setValue = null;
                        try
                        {
                            setValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvValue) && eachProperty.PropertyType != typeof(string) ? Activator.CreateInstance(eachProperty.PropertyType) : Convert.ChangeType(csvValue, eachProperty.PropertyType, ParseCulture);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                }
            }

            return returnEntity;
        }
```

Attributes class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]  



 public class CSVColumn : Attribute
    {
        public string ImportName { set; get; }

        public CSVColumn() { }

        public CSVColumn(string _import)
        {
            this.ImportName = _import;

        }
    }
```